# Java variable is incremented out of bounds at beginning of for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

The last for loop in the `BowlingTeamDemo2` class increments `x` to the value of `4` within the first iteration. Stumped...The program will auto fill the names instead of using the scanner, just for testing purposes. I have added a printout of the variable `x` before and after the inner loop in the last for loop to test the value of `x`. Before the inner loop, the value is `0`, after the inner loop starts, the value is `4`. 
The loop prints the name of the team correctly, but fails when attempting to access the `getMember()` method from the `BowlingTeam` class. This was an example, not an exercise.

The error I get is this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>   at BowlingTeam.getMember(BowlingTeam.java:21)     at 
>   BowlingTeamDemo2.main(BowlingTeamDemo2.java:41)

```
public class BowlingTeam{

    private String teamName;
    private String[] members = new String[4];

    public void setTeamName(String team){
        teamName = team;
    }
    public String getTeamName(){
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setMember(int number, String name){
        members[number] = name;
    }
    public String getMember(int number){
        // We have an issue here!!!!!!
        return members[number];
    }
}

import java.util.*;
public class BowlingTeamDemo2{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String name;
        final int NUM_TEAMS = 4;
        final int NUM_TEAM_MEMBERS = 4;
        int x;
        int y;

        BowlingTeam[] teams = new BowlingTeam[NUM_TEAMS];

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(y = 0; y < NUM_TEAMS; ++y){
            teams[y] = new BowlingTeam();
            System.out.println("Enter team name >> ");
            name = "Teams";
            teams[y].setTeamName(name);

            for(x = 0; x < NUM_TEAM_MEMBERS; ++x){
                System.out.println("Enter team members name >> ");
                name = "CoolName";
                teams[y].setMember(x, name);
            }
        }

        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        for(y = 0; y < NUM_TEAMS; ++y){
            System.out.println(x);

            for(x = 0; x < NUM_TEAM_MEMBERS; ++x);{
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println("\nMembers of team " +
                                teams[y].getTeamName());
                // We have an issue here!!!!!!
                System.out.print(teams[y].getMember(x) + " ");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo. `for(x = 0; x < NUM_TEAM_MEMBERS; ++x);{` has a semicolon terminating the loop body before the `{`.

Comment: Holy crap, thank you.

Comment: @JustaGuy This happens to everyone, no worries! By the way, the "Holy crap" button on Stack Overflow is [delete] :-)

Comment: 2 days wasted... I hate semicolons. Semicolons have most likely ruined relationships, jobs, jobs that depend on those jobs, and caused stress related injuries.

Comment: @JustaGuy anyway I posted a answer.

Comment: Am I supposed to mark this as answered somehow? Thank you for the quick responses btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your for loop has wrong syntax and it should be like this.

```
for(y = 0; y < NUM_TEAMS; ++y){
        System.out.println(x);

        for(x = 0; x < NUM_TEAM_MEMBERS; ++x){
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println("\nMembers of team " +
                            teams[y].getTeamName());
            // We have an issue here!!!!!!
            System.out.print(teams[y].getMember(x) + " ");
        }
    }
```